# How to work programmatically with MBR and sectors of USB flash?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, cross-platform, usb-flash-drive

I develop application and write in Java. My application needs access to MBR of USB flash and to content of its sectors. I thought about using JNI: call methods in Java, their implementation is in C++, use only standard C functions, no WinAPI, no Linux API.

And I don't know about possibility of working with such devices in Java without C++.

Tell me please the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on *nix, you can just access `/dev/sda` directly. You'll probably want to use a `FileChannel` to read and write at arbitrary offsets. Windows is a different story.

Comment: could you please explain the process

Comment: @PawanYadav If you're having an issue with a specific part of this, you should ask it as a separate question.